# how to set the time interval in javascript

Tags: javascript, excel

I am using html5 and javascript..i have some code in which i am reading some value from excel file ..here is the code

```
 var xVal = 1;
 var yVal = 2

 function readdata(x,y) {
    x = xVal;
    y = yVal;
    try {
       var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
       excel.Visible = false;
       var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open("D:\\Test.xls");
       //alert(excel_file.worksheets.count);
       var excel_sheet = excel_file.Worksheets("Sheet1");

   for(i=0;i<5;i++)
   {
        var data = excel_sheet.Cells(i,2).Value;
        drawWithexcelValue(data);
       }        
}
catch (ex) {
    alert(ex);
}
```

this is my code to read excel file ...while i am running it gives  an error Expected";"..i dont know where do i keep the ;

We have for loop to evaluate next value ...i want to know that how to give time interval between every execution , say it will stop for particular time before taking next value..and secondly 
i am hardcoding the value i<5; ..i want to know that is there any function through which i can read full excel file ...

Comment: You are missing a trailing `}` to close the function, unless you forgot to paste it. Also you are not declaring `i` in the for loop which makes it a global variable which could have consequences. Other than that i don't see anything wrong, but the problem could be in the function `drawWithexcelValue` which you haven't disclosed

Comment: there is no problem with draWithexcelValue it is running fine..i think the for loop is the problem

Comment: pretty sure you are missing a closing bracket there

Answer (score 0):

How are you defining "full file"? Excel has very large number of possible rows, I think what you want is a loop that ends when you hit an empty row.

```
while(1) {
   var data = excel_sheet.Cells(i,2).Value;
   if(data === ''){ // or undefined?
        break;
    } else {
       drawWithexcelValue(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: sir can i ask why u used 1 in while ..And i am said to say that your code is not working ..though i am intrested  in this way..please update your code

Comment: `while (1)` is saying `while(true)`, ie, do this indefinitely until `break` is reached.  I think the code needs to have i incremented somewhere in the else block.

Comment: @user2529216 As this is running in JavaScript it would perhaps be best to use `if (!data)` which should pick up any non-*falsy* value. However, I expect Excel to return the empty string '' for an empty cell.

Answer (score 0):

You have not said what line creates the error, but the specific error message you receive suggests this line:

```
var yVal = 2
```

which is missing a semi-colon at the end. JavaScript statements are semi-colon terminated. This would not usually create an error though, unless you are using `use strict`.

You can investigate JavaScript's `setInterval` to create the delay(s).. once you've got the current code working.